# Remove inline style sheets from data caption

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, jquery-ui, jquery-events

I am using inline style sheets for my data-caption value. How do I remove the inline style sheets and define it in a class? Since the value comes from the data-caption attribute, I don't know how to do it. Providing my code below:

http://jsfiddle.net/rajkumart08/8YK2n/

```
<div  class="cubeCell" data-text="Search" class="desktopContactImage cubeCell"
   data-caption="&lt;a style='padding-left: 40px; font-size: 18px; color: grey;' href='http://www.w3schools.com/' &gt;Create&lt;/a&gt; &lt;div&gt; &lt;a style='padding-left: 40px; font-size: 18px; color: grey;' &gt;View/Edit&lt;/a&gt; &lt;/div&gt; &lt;a style='padding-left: 40px; font-size: 18px; color: grey;' &gt;Labels&lt;/a&gt;"
   data-image="http://intra.defie.co/images/Desktop_icons_02.07.13/search.png"></div>

   <div class="iphoneContactImage" data-caption="&lt;a style='margin-left: 92px; font-size: 18px; color: grey;' href='http://www.w3schools.com/' &gt;Create&lt;/a&gt; &lt;div&gt; &lt;a style='margin-left: 92px; font-size: 18px; color: grey;' &gt;View/Edit&lt;/a&gt; &lt;/div&gt; &lt;a style='margin-left: 92px; font-size: 18px; color: grey;' &gt;Labels&lt;/a&gt;"
      data-image="http://intra.defie.co/images/Desktop_icons_02.07.13/demoImage.png">iphoneImage</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

One solution is to parse the styles using Javascript (First answer of this question: [Can jQuery get all CSS styles associated with an element?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/754607/can-jquery-get-all-css-styles-associated-with-an-element)) and create a function to dump them into and style.

Then, you can add this style to your page dynamically (First answer of this question: [How to dynamically create CSS class in JavaScript and apply?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1720320/how-to-dynamically-create-css-class-in-javascript-and-apply)).

**EDIT:**

To access to `data-caption` attribute, you can use `$('.cubeCell').attr('data-caption')` and it will return an string containing the style in plain text:

`&lt;a style='padding-left: 40px; font-size: 18px; color: grey;' href='http://www.w3schools.com/' &gt;Create&lt;/a&gt; &lt;div&gt; &lt;a style='padding-left: 40px; font-size: 18px; color: grey;' &gt;View/Edit&lt;/a&gt; &lt;/div&gt; &lt;a style='padding-left: 40px; font-size: 18px; color: grey;' &gt;Labels&lt;/a&gt;`

That it's the same to (substituing HTML characters):

```
<a style='padding-left: 40px; font-size: 18px; color: grey;' href='http://www.w3schools.com/' >Create</a>
<div>
   <a style='padding-left: 40px; font-size: 18px; color: grey;' >View/Edit</a>
</div>
<a style='padding-left: 40px; font-size: 18px; color: grey;' >Labels</a>
```

So it seems like you have more than only styles in `data-caption` attribute. You should parse this string using a [Regular Expression](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp) to retrieve only `styles`. Then you will be able to create the correct styles and add them to your page using Javascript. ([how to get style="i want the css code" using regexp (javascript)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3597283/how-to-get-style-i-want-the-css-code-using-regexp-javascript))

**EDIT 2:**

Suppose that you already have the style in an string:

```
var mystyle = 'padding-left: 40px; font-size: 18px; color: grey;';
```

And you want to apply it to an element that already have an style inline, like your example. I will do it in the following way:

**1)** Take the HTML of the element (without `style` attribute) and assign
    it to where it belongs. For example:

*Original code*:

```
<div id="mylink">
    <a style='padding-left: 40px; font-size: 18px; color: grey;' href='http://www.w3schools.com/'>Create</a>
</div>
```

*JS*:

```
$('#mylink').html('<a href='http://www.w3schools.com/'>Create</a>');
```

*Resulting code*:

```
<div id="mylink">
    <a href='http://www.w3schools.com/'>Create</a>
</div>
```

**2)** Now, add your own class to handle the style:

```
$('#mylink a').addClass('mystyle');
```

**3)** Finally, you only need to create the `style` element and add it to your page:

```
var style = document.createElement('style');
var mystyle = 'padding-left: 40px; font-size: 18px; color: grey;';
style.type = 'text/css';
style.innerHTML = '.mystyle { ' + mystyle + ' }';
document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(style);
```

Don't forget to respect the order of your code lines so your code execute and apply styles succesfully.

Comment: but how to retrieve the css from data-caption= attribute using css or id

Comment: @user2045025 I edited my own answer to provide you more information :)

Comment: yeah but how to remove the styles from html and put it in css or js style='padding-left: 40px; font-size: 18px; color: grey;'

Comment: @user2045025 I re-edited my own answer. It's hard for me to do your specific problem, but I think that can give to you some ideas of how should be done.

Comment: thanks for your reply.....its slightly confusing can you update in this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/rajkumart08/8YK2n/

Comment: what does this line of code does document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(style);